# Returning an Array of Structs (Partially working) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

We are trying to return an array of structures to print the contents in the main. When debugging the code, we get to the line right before the return statement and it shows that it is holding the right contents which is an `int` and then a `string` (`playerID` and `name`). As soon as the return statement executes the array is returned to the `main` but only the `playerID` is held in the array. All of the values for `name` have been lost. Can someone explain why this would happen and a possible solution? If further clarification is needed please let me know.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

struct Player 
 {
  int playerID;
  string name;
  };

Player *fillPlayers();

int main() 
{
 Player *myPlayerPointer;
 myPlayerPointer = fillPlayers();
 return 0;
}

Player * fillPlayers() {
 ifstream file1;
 Player * fullPlayerPointer = new Player[244];
 Player ourPlayers[244];
 file1.open("Players.txt");
 if (file1.fail()) {
  cerr << "file1 did not open";
 }

 if (file1.is_open()){

 while (!file1.eof()){
  string size;
  getline(file1, size);
  for(int i = 0; i < 244; i++){
      file1 >> ourPlayers[i].playerID;
      file1 >> ourPlayers[i].name;
  }
 }
 file1.close();
}
 fullPlayerPointer = &ourPlayers[0];
 return fullPlayerPointer;
}
```

Comment: Please properly indent/format the code. TIA.

Comment: `std::vector` is really what you want here.

Comment: `while (!file1.eof())` is a common error that will bite you unless the file ends exactly where you think it does. Common results are one extra garbage entry being "read". Read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Sometimes a [better example of C++ techniques](http://ideone.com/cImOJn) suffices.  All of that pointer stuff is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

This code looks a lot like C code. In C++ we have fancy RAII containers like `std::vector` and `std::array` that will do exactly what you want.

As for the issue, you are not returning an array, instead you are returning a pointer to an `int`. You should check out [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array (C++ >= 11)

Comment: `std::vector` is not an *"RAII container"*. `std::vector` has stack semantics. Stack semantics are an important building block in implementing the RAII idiom.

Comment: @IInspectable: I've never heard of the term "stack semantics" in relation to C++, and do not believe it is formally any better than "RAII container". But we know what both of them mean.

Comment: @Lightness: Even if both are not formally correct, the version in this answer confuses the tool with the goal.

Comment: @IInspectable: So does "stack semantics". In fact, that one makes that mistake even more, by confusing "the stack" (some implementation detail) with the notion of automatic storage duration.

Comment: @Lightness: I used *stack semantics* to mean, that the lifetime and visibility of an object coincide. I wouldn't know of a better term to describe this, and I don't know whether *"automatic storage duration"* explicitly guarantees this.

Comment: @IInspectable: Isn't that literally what _automatic storage duration_ means?

Comment: @Lightness: If that is the case, then you are free to adjust my previous statements: `std::vector` is not an *"RAII container"*. Instances of `std::vector` can have automatic storage duration. Automatic storage duration is an important building block in implementing the RAII idiom.

Comment: @IInspectable: How does that make `std::vector` _not_ a "RAII container"? `std::vector` certainly implements RAII. It manages its internal memory automatically so that you don't have to. That's exactly what RAII means. Furthermore, it does so whether you give the vector itself automatic storage duration or not.

Comment: @Lightness: `std::vector` can be used for scope-based resource management, but `auto p{ new std::vector<X>() };` certainly isn't. It's still a `std::vector` but not RAII any more. Managing resources is only part of RAII, and `std::vector` implements that part. That doesn't turn a container into a programming idiom.

Comment: @IInspectable: It absolutely is still RAII. You have to delete the vector yourself but, when you do, it takes all its elements with it. That's what RAII _means_. RAII does not mean "my objects all have automatic storage duration".

Comment: @Lightness: That's what I tried to get across: Automatic resource management is **part** of RAII, and that part is implemented by `std::vector`. That doesn't make the container itself an *"RAII container"*. RAII is a programming idiom, and resource management containers are part of that. Anyway, if you still feel the compelling need to disagree, you get to have the last word.

Answer (score 0):

The generally correct answer is use a `std::vector` as it assists in managing ownership and the lifetime of storage as well as tracking the capacity and resizing itself as needed. But let's take a walk through `fillPlayers` to explain what is going wrong.

```
Player * fillPlayers()
{
    ifstream file1;
    Player * fullPlayerPointer = new Player[244];
```

Dynamically allocated 244 `Player`s. Dynamic storage has manually controlled lifetime and will remain valid until such time as it is freed. Unfortunately this allocated storage is never used and not put away correctly later with `delete[]` This allocation will be "leaked". As dire as this sounds, this is the "right" way to allocate the storage, but as we will see, the function uses it incorrectly.

```
    Player ourPlayers[244];
```

Statically allocated 244 `Player`s as a temporary variable. This variable will only exist inside the innermost set of surrounding curly braces `{}`. Afterward it will be rendered invalid. This means that references to `ourPlayers` should not be returned from this function as `ourPlayers` will be rendered invalid at the return from the function and before the caller can make use of it.

```
    file1.open("Players.txt");
    if (file1.fail())
    {
        cerr << "file1 did not open";
    }
```

Always test before using, so the above is almost right. It is rendered redundant by the next line performing a nearly identical test. This could be a good place to put an `else`, but the code is more easily read with `if (file1.is_open())` followed by an `else` to print the error message if it is not open.

Why do I say this? Because the programmer's intent with `is_open` is much easier to discern than with the broader term `fail`.

```
    if (file1.is_open())
    {

        while (!file1.eof())
```

Read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for details on why this is almost always the wrong solution to looping through a file.

```
        {
            string size;
            getline(file1, size);
```

Always test a read to ensure it succeeded. In addition, the file size was read and then not converted into an integer to use in the loop that follows.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 244; i++)
```

Regardless of how many entries there are in this file 244 will always be read. If the file does not have at least 244 entries, the read will fail and as the reads are not being checked for success, garbage will be stored in the array.

Also note that there is a loop iterating through 244 entries in the file that is surrounded by a loop that will attempt to read again until the EOF flag is set. Most likely you only want one such loop.

```
            {
                file1 >> ourPlayers[i].playerID;
                file1 >> ourPlayers[i].name;
            }
        }
        file1.close();
    }
    fullPlayerPointer = &ourPlayers[0];
```

The pointer to the dynamic allocation made earlier is overwritten by a pointer to the temporary allocation `ourPlayers`. A reference to long-term storage has been replaced by a reference to storage that is about to go out of scope and become invalid.

It is possible that OP intended this to copy the data in the short term storage to the long term storage, but unfortunately that's not what the compiler was told to do, and it's not really worth doing. It would be much more useful to directly read the file into the long term storage.

```
    return fullPlayerPointer;
```

Returns from the function and gives an invalid array to the caller.
    }

Lot to fix in there.

Here's a very simple approach that fixes all of the above problems but exposes a few more:

```
Player * fillPlayers()
{
    ifstream file1("Players.txt");

    Player * players = nullptr;
    if (file1.is_open())
    {
        int size;
        if (file1 >> size)
        {
            players = new Player[size];
            int index = 0;
            while (file1 >> players[index].playerID >> players[index].name
                    && index < size)
            {
            }
            // extra brains needed here to handle premature read failure. 
        }
        file1.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "file1 did not open";
    }

    return players; // only a pointer to the array was returned. How big the 
                    // array is and how many items are actually in it is lost 
}
```

This is where `std::vector` really becomes awesome. It knows how big it is and how full it is. An array doesn't.

Now, assuming std::vector is not allowed, and Paul McKenzie has already [covered what to do if it isn't](http://ideone.com/cImOJn), the smart thing to do is make a very simple wrapper around the array to get some modicum of the safety and ease of use `vector` provides.

```
class stupidvector
{
    Player *players;
    size_t capacity; // a typical vector implementation uses a pointer for
                     // this to make iteration easier
    size_t size; // vector uses pointer here, too.
public:

    stupidvector();
    stupidvector(size_t size);

    // correctly copy a stupid vector Rule of Three. In this case, don't 
    // allow it to be copied.
    stupidvector(const stupidvector& src)=delete;

    // correctly move a stupid vector Rule of Five
    stupidvector(stupidvector && src);

    // release storage
    ~stupidvector();

    // add an item to the end
    void push(const Player & player);

    // how big is it?
    size_t getcapacity();

    // how full is it?
    size_t getsize();

    // make it act like an array
    Player & operator[](size_t index);

    // correctly assign. Rule of Three. again we don't want to copy these,
    // but if we did, look at Copy and Swap Idiom for a neat solution
    stupidvector& operator=(const stupidvector& src) = delete;

    // correctly move
    stupidvector& operator=(stupidvector && src);
};
```

Pay special attention to the [Rules of Three and Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)